# Replace "OS agnostic" newlines

Tags: ruby

I have several different document formats coming in. I'd like to strip out all the newlines and replace them with a `" "`. How can I account for newlines other than `"\n"`?

Something like `s.gsub("\n", " ")`

Comment: "How can I account for newlines other than "\n"?" Not to be pedantic, but there is a difference between `"\n"` AKA new-line, and `"\r"`, which is carriage-return. Either one, or a combination of the two, can be called a line-end. Keeping the terminology straight will help if you're dealing with a lot of text files and needing to work with other developers. I'd go nuts trying to figure out what you meant if you said you wanted to strip newlines but meant carriage-returns.

Comment: I appreciate the advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most operating systems use `\n` or `\r` (or a combination) for newlines.

`s.gsub(/[\n\r]+/, " ")` should do the trick.

`/[\n\r]+/` is known as a regular expression. It matches `\n`, `\r` and any combination of the two.

Answer (score 0):

To make it your code more readable you could however use my [gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/linebreak).

You can install it this way:

```
gem install linebreak
```

You can use it this way:

```
require 'aef/linebreak/string_extension'

"Something\n".linebreak_encode(" ")
# => "Something "
```

Other examples:

```
"Something\n".linebreak_encode(:windows)
# => "Something\r\n"

"Something\r\n".linebreak_encode(:unix)
# => "Something\n"
```

It additionally comes with a commandline tool. Documentation can be found [here](http://rubydoc.info/gems/linebreak/1.3.1/frames).